# DataGridView has only blank cells

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview

In my early vb project, Im pulling SQL Server data to GridView. The datatable is being properly populated with data. But upon assigning it to the Gridview I see only blank cells are added. I ve given the code below for reference. Could you pls anybody point the real issue ?

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim ProductsTable As New DataTable
    Private myCmd As SqlCommand
    Private myReader As SqlDataReader
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Db1DataSet1.contacts' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

    End Sub

    Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MainMenu.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-ULJLSF8\MMSQL2008;Initial Catalog=products;Integrated Security=True;")

        Dim Sqlc As New SqlCommand("SELECT id,barcode FROM dbo.items", conn)
        conn.Open()


        Dim DataReader As SqlDataReader = Sqlc.ExecuteReader()
        ProductsTable.Load(DataReader)
        ProductsTable.AcceptChanges()

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ProductsTable


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You should declare `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` with `Using` statements, it will also close the connection for you. If you want to keep that DataTable, declare it as `Private ProductsTable As DataTable = Nothing`, then `ProductsTable?.Dispose()` before you create a new instance to load it.

Comment: Are you using predefined columns in your datagridview?

Comment: @jimi I temporarily fixed the issue by assigning the DGView with a dataset and emptying it on form load. So that it works well with the prepared data on the button click. Thank you all for support.